# Javascript: Javascript ignores the elements generated by itself

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript function that generates new selects with IDs:

```
function generateChild(root, categories){
 ++counter;
    var appendid = "id='selectCategory_".concat(counter);
    var coma = "'";
    var mayorque = "'>";
    var appendcoma = appendid.concat(coma);
    var select ="<div class='selectContainer'".concat(appendcoma);
    var close = "><select ";
    var cerrar = select.concat(close);
    var appendidselect = cerrar.concat(appendid);
    var html = appendidselect.concat(mayorque);
    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        html += "<option value='" + categories[i] + "'>" + categories[i] + "</option>";
    }
    html += '</select></div>';


    // ---------------------------

    // ---------------------------
    // create an element from the html string
    // ---------------------------
    var tplt = root.createElement('template');
    tplt.innerHTML = html;
    var el = tplt.content.firstChild;
    // ---------------------------

    // ---------------------------
    // attach the change handler
    // ---------------------------
    el.firstChild.addEventListener("change", handle_onChange);
    // ---------------------------

    return el;
    }
}
```

And then this function to search for the last dropdown that didn't have a blank space on it, and save it in a hidden input for later use:

```
  if(this.value == ' '){
        for (var i = counter - 1 ; i >= 0 ; --i){
            var string = i.toString();
            var selectid = "selectCategory_".concat(string);
            if(document.getElementById(selectid)){
                document.getElementById("category").value = document.getElementById(selectid).value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        var lastselectedvalue = this.value;
        document.getElementById("category").value = this.value;
    }
```

This works well with the first dropdown, which is already in the code:

```
    <input type ="hidden" name="category" id = "category" value="">
        <div id="category0" class="selectContainer">
            <select id="selectCategory_0">
            <option>something</option>
            <option>something else</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

But never works with the other dropdowns, it always returns undefined.

Comment: You have to append the generated elements to the page first: `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(yourNewElement);`

Comment: I do it later on the code: `parentContainer.insertBefore(childContainer, this.nextSibling);`

Comment: If it's later on it's still too late. You'd have to append the content before trying to reference it's child elements. I may be wrong here.